# include a file from seperate folder in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

well, I am trying to include a header file in my project, while the header actually belongs to the other project in the same workspace. 
I don't want to do something like 
../../folder_name/header_file_name.
If it helps I am using VisualC++ 6.0.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the path to the header file in your Project Settings > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601268/visual-c-include-files-from-other-projects-in-the-same-solution - This article should help

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the relative (or the full) path to the header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Visual C++ 6.0, go to Tools / Options / Directories / Show directories for: Include files, and then add the full path to the folder where your other header file resides.

Answer (score 2):

```
 1. Right-click on the project, and select Properties.
 2. Select Configuration Properties->C/C++->General.
 3. Set the path under Additional Include Directories.
```

Comment: Not according to this -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278349(v=vs.60).aspx which states that it is under C/C++ -> Preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Add the other folder as an Include Directory to your project, so that it's in the search path.

You may also need to add a Library Directory if this header has a corresponding object file.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell to compiler a path to search header files.
Look at your project configuration.
Look at to the first pict here: http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc6.html