# Linking two projects in a Visual studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, projects

I am having two projects in one solution called SOL, using Visual Studio: project 1 and project 2

In each of projects: I am having some headers and cpp files.

In project 2, I want to use a header existing in project 1:

```
#include "proj1.h"
```

I am having an error which states that the file doesn't exist:

```
 Error  2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'proj1.h': No such file or directory C:\Users\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SOL\proj2.cpp  28
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual c++: #include files from other projects in the same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601268/visual-c-include-files-from-other-projects-in-the-same-solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using VS 2012 but AFAIK for this subject this is nearly the same.

- Open the project properties page of project 2. Right-click on project 2 in the solution explorer and select "Properties".
- In the C/C++ section select "General".
- Find the line "Additional Include Directories" and add "$(SolutionDir)project 1". This is a semicolon separated list but you can as well choose to edit this field, then you get a list view.

Comment: This only works if the other project is in a subdirectory of the solution, which is not generally the case.

Comment: and it only links the header files so you will end up in unresolved external dependencies if you have any cpp file in the other project...