# Visual Studio - Share source files between projects in a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have an overall solution with two projects (let's say `proj1` and `proj2`) within it. In `proj1` there's a file called `foo.cpp` and a corresponding `foo.h`. In `proj2`  I use `#include "../proj1/foo.h"` so that's taken care of, but I get linker errors, and I suspect this is because it doesn't have access to `foo.obj`.

Is there a way to set up the project preferences so that `proj2` can link to `proj1` source files without having to copy them over from project to project? I'm not linking to any external libraries if that makes it easier.

Comment: This has already been answered at this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601268/visual-c-include-files-from-other-projects-in-the-same-solution

Comment: @Zimad But both `proj1` and `proj2` create `.exe` files not `.lib` files

Comment: There is no need to make a copy of the source file. Just right click somewhere in the second project, go to `Add | Existing Item...` and browse to the source file in the tree of the other project.

Comment: @Steve I tried that but I still get the linker errors

Comment: Did you add the `.cpp` file to the project, or just the header? Without the implementation, you'll get unresolved external errors from the linker.

Comment: Post the linker errors.  It sounds like you aren't linking to the .obj file, but we can't tell without seeing the errors.  What you did with the .h file is correct.

Comment: @Steve I added just the `.cpp` and set the `Additional Include Directory` to the where the `.h` files are.