# Gtest test project link to other executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I have a project that I added a gtest project to, then turned the original project into a .lib project and called its main() function from a 3rd, new project. This way, I can build the test .exe with the project .exe. Except, it's not working.

**These are the steps I've followed as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4222169)**
Create or open a project, then create a Win32 Console Application test project for it.
Right click the test project, go to properties, and set Configuration to debug.
Go to Configuration Properties **>** C/C++ **>** General **>** Additional Include Directories and add the gtest includes folder.
Under Code Generation **>** Runtime Library, choose MDt or MTd; whatever is used by the project to be tested.
Under Linker **>** General **>** Additional Library Directories, add a reference to the folder with gtestd.lib.
Under Input **>** Additional Dependencies, add gtestd.lib.
Right click the test project, go to properties, and set Configuration to release, then perform steps 3 and 4.
Under Linker **>** General **>** Additional Library Directories, add a reference to the folder with gtest.lib.
Under Input **>** Additional Dependencies, add gtest.lib.

**These are the steps I've followed for linking the test project, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601285)**
Right click the test project, go to Build Dependencies **>** Project Dependencies, and add the project to be tested.
Go to Properties **>** C/C++ **>** General **>** Additional Include Directories and include headers from the project to test.
Under Linker **>** Input **>** Additional Dependencies, enter the .lib file of the project

**Here is the problem**
For some reason, the test project surprisingly works, but only in *release* mode. The wrapper project doesn't work in either mode, despite having the same settings as the test project. I've looked at 20 possible solutions and have yet to find one. I also tried *__declspec(dllexport)* in front of every method in the library project, but that doesn't do any justice. VS is fighting me tooth-and-nail.

**Other stuff I tried**
I don't want to change the project to build a .lib every time I need to test. So I looked into creating both a *.exe* and *.lib* from the project using a pre-link build event, but it seems to only take console commands and I couldn't figure out how to hook up the resulting .lib file from the console commands I got from another SO answer.

Here is the current .sln file with these problems. URLs are absolute: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6r81tGW7hODeXNpR3ROc3hYMWc/view?usp=sharing

*How do I simply make a test project and wrapper project to launch a normal project (that works in both debug and release mode)?*

Comment: I'm asking for the normal project as a .lib, a test project, and a wrapper to launch the .lib project. There are no blogs or documentation that do all three points, so I supplemented with advice from other areas, but it doesn't work. What posts say I should do (linker -> include libraries, C++ -> General -> add include headers here) is apparently insufficient. I've set up for debug and release mode. Now I'm wondering if people just pretend that it works; this is beyond difficult.

By the way, I'll take a working .sln file at this point without complaint or further question.

Comment: Every resource I listed and similar questions were on Stack Overflow so I didn't think about whether this fit the site or not. On the other hand, I can't say it would do well in superuser unless they like to discuss project config, so I don't know if a migration would be useful. What I do know is that if it does get answered, somebody will appreciate it :) There is a critical lack of working gtest examples in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes:

1. In SimpleCalc (debug), change `Project | Properties | General | Configuration type` to `Static Library`. This is why Release worked but Debug didn't.
2. For SimpleCalcWrapper, select `Project | Add reference...` and add SimpleCalc. This is why SimpleCalcWrapper didn't work.
3. For SimpleCalcTest (release), reset to default `Project | Properties | Linker | Advanced | Import Library` or SimpleCalcTest.exe will not compile.
4. For SimpleCalcTest, change `Project | Properties | C/C++ | Additional Include Directories` to `$(SolutionDir)\gtest\include;$(SolutionDir)\SimpleCalc;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`. This will have them relative to the project.
5. For SimpleCalcTest, change `Project | Properties | Linker | Additional Library Directories` to `$(SolutionDir)\gtest;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)` - you don't need SimpleCalc directory because the project is added to references.
6. For SimpleCalcWrapper, change `Project | Properties | C/C++ | Additional Include Directories` to `$(SolutionDir)\SimpleCalc;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`
7. For SimpleCalcWrapper, reset to default `Project | Properties | Linker | Additional Library Directories` - you don't need SimpleCalc directory because the project is added to references.

Comment: Fantastic. It looks like I performed the steps wrong, probably between the debug/release versions. I know I tried to fix it using a hodgepodge of answers I *thought* I was able to undo correctly. Thanks especially for the $(SolutionDir) tip.